# SQL - Create ID's group from specific row until end of the group

Tags: sql

I'm trying to generate an ID for identifying web sessions for specific events. In the next table, each instance represents when the time of the event sent:

| original_timestamp | session_start |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-17 23:53:21 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 00:05:36 | 0 |
| 2021-01-18 00:07:16 | 0 |
| 2021-01-18 10:39:06 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 10:39:06 | 0 |
| 2021-01-18 15:59:48 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 16:00:07 | 0 |
| 2021-01-19 00:45:17 | 1 |
| 2021-01-19 01:11:40 | 1 |

I'd like to create an incremental unique id from the first session_start = 1 until the next one (excluded) for getting this output:

| original_timestamp | session_start | unique_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-17 23:53:21 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 00:05:36 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 00:07:16 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-01-18 10:39:06 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-18 10:39:06 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-01-18 15:59:48 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-18 16:00:07 | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-01-19 00:45:17 | 1 | 4 |
| 2021-01-19 01:11:40 | 1 | 5 |

In other words, each session_start = 1 should increase the unique_id. I've been breaking my head trying to work this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With SUM() window function:

```
SELECT *, SUM(session_start) OVER (ORDER BY original_timestamp) unique_id
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8ff31ccf3c16a087a2fbb49ff1538d7).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ! It's exactly what I need. Question: If I had more columns like for example user_id and I want to do the same but also aggregating by user_id, how should I change that query? Thanks !

Comment: @Aceconhielo (if I understand what you want to do) the difference would be a PARTITION clause inside OVER: `OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY original_timestamp)`

Comment: Please remember to accept the answear if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any database that supports OLAP functions
Also adding a user_id:

```
WITH
-- your input with user_id...
indata(user_id,orig_ts,start_flg) AS (
          SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-17 23:53:21',1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 00:05:36',0
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 00:07:16',0
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 10:39:06',1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 10:39:06',0
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 15:59:48',1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 16:00:07',0
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-19 00:45:17',1
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-19 01:11:40',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-17 23:53:21',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 00:05:36',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 00:07:16',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 10:39:06',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 10:39:06',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 15:59:48',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-18 16:00:07',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-19 00:45:17',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-19 01:11:40',1
)
-- end of your input , replace following "," with "WITH" ...
,
-- calculating my own session start ...
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN orig_ts - LAG(orig_ts,1,'0000-01-01') OVER(
                          PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY orig_ts
                        ) > '20 minutes'
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS calc_flg
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  user_id
, orig_ts
, start_flg
, calc_flg
, SUM(calc_flg) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY orig_ts) AS session_id
FROM with_counter
ORDER BY user_id,orig_ts;
-- out  user_id |       orig_ts       | start_flg | calc_flg | session_id 
-- out ---------+---------------------+-----------+----------+------------
-- out        1 | 2021-01-17 23:53:21 |         1 |        1 |          1
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 00:05:36 |         0 |        0 |          1
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 00:07:16 |         0 |        0 |          1
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 10:39:06 |         1 |        1 |          2
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 10:39:06 |         0 |        0 |          2
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 15:59:48 |         1 |        1 |          3
-- out        1 | 2021-01-18 16:00:07 |         0 |        0 |          3
-- out        1 | 2021-01-19 00:45:17 |         1 |        1 |          4
-- out        1 | 2021-01-19 01:11:40 |         1 |        1 |          5
-- out        2 | 2021-01-17 23:53:21 |         1 |        1 |          1
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 00:05:36 |         0 |        0 |          1
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 00:07:16 |         0 |        0 |          1
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 10:39:06 |         1 |        1 |          2
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 10:39:06 |         0 |        0 |          2
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 15:59:48 |         1 |        1 |          3
-- out        2 | 2021-01-18 16:00:07 |         0 |        0 |          3
-- out        2 | 2021-01-19 00:45:17 |         1 |        1 |          4
-- out        2 | 2021-01-19 01:11:40 |         1 |        1 |          5
```

Depending on the database you are using - and did not specify - , one DBMS I know has a more elegant way of computing a session ID in the manner we're doing here ....