# SQL create a new field sessions given the value of another field

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have problems approaching the following task.

Given a table like

```
|    user_id    |    hit_id    |  new_session |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|       1       |       1      |       0      |
|       1       |       2      |       0      |
|       1       |       3      |       1      |
|       1       |       4      |       0      |
|      ...      |      ...     |      ...     |
|       5       |      19      |       0      |
```

where

- the combination of `user_id` and `hit_id` is unique
- `new_session` is a boolean that determines if the hit started a new session or not for this particular user

I want to create a new column, `session_number` that splits hit_ids into sessions, taking into account that:

- the first row for each `user_id`, once ordered by `hit_id asc` gets a value of 1 for the new column `session_number`
- as long as `new_session` is 0, the value of `session_number` stays the same
- when `new_session` is 1, I have to sum up 1 to the actual session count
- the logic works over a partition by `user_id` ordered by `hit_id asc`, and therefore once the `user_id` changes, the session count is reset

I have created a [db-fiddle with some example data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j3LsbpJN9torTPUEficnjC/0)

The expected output for `user_id = 1` (which cover multiple corner cases) would be:

```
|    user_id    |    hit_id    |  new_session | session_number |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|----------------|
|       1       |       1      |       0      |        1       |
|       1       |       2      |       0      |        1       |
|       1       |       3      |       1      |        2       |
|       1       |       4      |       0      |        2       |
|       1       |       5      |       0      |        2       |
|       1       |       6      |       1      |        3       |
|       1       |       7      |       0      |        3       |
|       1       |       8      |       1      |        4       |
|       1       |       8      |       1      |        5       |
```

I have tried with a combination of lag(), rank(), and dense_rank(), but I always find a corner case that makes all the attempts unsuccessful. Additionally, I am totally sure that there is a very easy approach for that that I am not taking into account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Create ID's group from specific row until end of the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153019/sql-create-ids-group-from-specific-row-until-end-of-the-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select pv.*,
       (1 + sum(new_session) over (partition by user_id order by hit_id)) as session_number
from pageviews pv;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WoFHoY6nF8T67XyU9enJP/0) is a db-fiddle.

Comment: ::facepalm:: why things looks so easy when others do them :). It is exactly what I needed